# using sbt for multi project build

Tags: sbt

I am totally new to SBT. Suppose I have three Scala projects: project_a, project_b, project_c. How should I go about building all three projects into one jar file? Suppose I use project_a as the root project. The directory structure is like

```
--project_a
  --build.sbt
--project_b
--project_c
```

Following the instructions on sbt webiste, I created a build.sbt file, which looks something like

```
lazy val root = (project.in(file("."))).aggregate(project_b, project_c)
lazy val project_b = project
lazy val project_c = project
```

I put the build.sbt under the project_a. When I run sbt clean compile under project_a, a new (kinda of empty) project_b and project_c folders are created under the folder project_a. However, in the build.sbt file, I meant project_b and project_c to refer to the original folders I already created which contains the source and test code, and which are outside project_a.

Can someone let me know what I did wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your [multi-project](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html) setup is not right.

Getting Started guide says:

> Aggregation means that running a task on the aggregate project will also run it on the aggregated projects.

- If you have `project_a` that uses `project_b` and `project_c`, then you need `root` *in addition* to `project_a`, `project_b`, and `project_c`.
- Root can aggregate all three (a, b, and c), but it only aggregates commands given to sbt shell, for instance for compiling all three at the same time.
- `project_a` should be set up to depend on `project_b` and `project_c`.

Here's an example:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  scalaVersion := "2.11.4",
  organization := "com.example"
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  aggregate(project_a, project_b, project_c).
  settings(commonSettings: _*)

lazy val project_a = project.
  dependsOn(project_b, project_c).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    // your settings here
  )

lazy val project_b = project.
  settings(commonSettings: _*)

lazy val project_c = project.
  settings(commonSettings: _*)
```

> How should I go about building all three projects into one jar file?

1. If you just want *.class files from your own projects, you can see an example on [Macro Projects](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Macro-Projects.html#Distribution).
2. If you want *.class files and library dependencies, you need sbt-assembly.